# how to connect protoge(OWL file)with java

Tags: java, jena, owl, protege

Can anyone give me at least one idea to how can I connect java with protoge?
how can I access OWL using jena API in java?!

Answer (score 0):

The Jena website has plenty of tutorials available. If you have difficulties getting started, please post the code that does not work and we'll help you along.

First tutorial [here](https://jena.apache.org/tutorials/rdf_api.html)

```
// some definitions 
static String personURI = "http://somewhere/JohnSmith"; 
static String fullName = "John Smith"; 
// create an empty Model 
Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel(); 
// create the resource 
Resource johnSmith = model.createResource(personURI); 
// add the property
johnSmith.addProperty(VCARD.FN, fullName);
```

In order to make this work, you'll need the right imports. Assuming that the Java technicalities are not a problem, this example shows how to create a statement and add it to a model, i.e., an rdf file.

From the same page you can get to more complex material, including OWL tutorials.

You have not mentioned which task you're trying to carry out. Can you describe it?

Comment: I don't have the point that I'll start from that .. and codes in jena Docs. cannot help me that much !

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by start point. What code have you tried? Which part of my example is not clear?